# Conference track management

Tags: python, object-oriented, datetime

I was learning my way on designing real world OOP problems and I was trying to solve this problem in the OOP way. The problem statement is as follows:

> - The conference has multiple tracks each of which has a morning and afternoon session.
> - Each session contains multiple talks.
> - Morning sessions begin at 9am and must finish by 12 noon, for lunch.
> - Afternoon sessions begin at 1pm and must finish in time for the networking event.
> - The networking event can start no earlier than 4:00 and no later than 5:00.
> - No talk title has numbers in it.
> - All talk lengths are either in minutes (not hours) or lightning (5 minutes).
> - Presenters will be very punctual; there needs to be no gap between sessions.
>
> ### Test input
>
> ```
> Writing Fast Tests Against Enterprise Rails 60min
> Overdoing it in Python 45min
> Lua for the Masses 30min
> Ruby Errors from Mismatched Gem Versions 45min
> Common Ruby Errors 45min
> Rails for Python Developers lightning
> Communicating Over Distance 60min
> Accounting-Driven Development 45min
> Woah 30min
> Sit Down and Write 30min
> Pair Programming vs Noise 45min
> Rails Magic 60min
> Ruby on Rails: Why We Should Move On 60min
> Clojure Ate Scala (on my project) 45min
> Programming in the Boondocks of Seattle 30min
> Ruby vs. Clojure for Back-End Development 30min
> Ruby on Rails Legacy App Maintenance 60min
> A World Without HackerNews 30min
> User Interface CSS in Rails Apps 30min
> ```
>
> ### Test output
>
> ```
> Track 1:
> 09:00AM Writing Fast Tests Against Enterprise Rails 60min
> 10:00AM Communicating Over Distance 60min
> 11:00AM Rails Magic 60min
> 12:00PM Lunch
> 01:00PM Ruby on Rails: Why We Should Move On 60min
> 02:00PM Common Ruby Errors 45min
> 02:45PM Accounting-Driven Development 45min
> 03:30PM Pair Programming vs Noise 45min
> 04:15PM User Interface CSS in Rails Apps 30min
> 04:45PM Rails for Python Developers lightning
> 04:50PM Networking Event
>
> Track 2:
> 09:00AM Ruby on Rails Legacy App Maintenance 60min
> 10:00AM Overdoing it in Python 45min
> 10:45AM Ruby Errors from Mismatched Gem Versions 45min
> 11:30AM Lua for the Masses 30min
> 12:00PM Lunch
> 01:00PM Clojure Ate Scala (on my project) 45min
> 01:45PM Woah 30min
> 02:15PM Sit Down and Write 30min
> 02:45PM Programming in the Boondocks of Seattle 30min
> 03:15PM Ruby vs. Clojure for Back-End Development 30min
> 03:45PM A World Without HackerNews 30min
> 04:15PM Networking Event
> ```

I successfully finished designing the problem and it works perfectly but I would love to see the experts opinion on my code and provide suggestions.

**timing.py**

```python
from datetime import timedelta, datetime


class Timing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.morning_start = (datetime.min+ timedelta(hours=9)).strftime('%I:%M %p')
        self.lunch = (datetime.min+ timedelta(hours=12)).strftime('%I:%M %p')
        self.afternoon_start = (datetime.min+ timedelta(hours=13)).strftime('%I:%M %p')
        self.day_end = (datetime.min+ timedelta(hours=17)).strftime('%I:%M %p')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Timing()
    print(a.afternoon_start)
```

**track.py**

```python
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

from .timing import Timing


class Track(Timing):
    id = 0

    def __init__(self):
        super(Track, self).__init__()
        Track.id += 1
        self.talks = {}
        self.talk_list = Track.extract_input()

    @staticmethod
    def extract_input():
        __talks = {}
        lines = []
        try:
            lines = [line.strip() for line in open('test.txt')]
        except FileNotFoundError as e:
            print('File Not Found', e)
        for line in lines:
            title, minutes = line.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
            try:
                minutes = int(minutes[:-3])
            # negative indexing raises error, so it means it's lightning
            except ValueError:
                minutes = 5
            __talks[line] = minutes
        return __talks

    def get_talks(self, start_talk, end_talk):
        start = timedelta(hours=start_talk)
        for key, value in list(self.talk_list.items()):
            prev = start + timedelta(minutes=int(value))
            if prev <= timedelta(hours=end_talk):
                self.talks[(datetime.min + start).strftime('%I:%M %p')] = key
                self.talk_list.popitem()
                start += timedelta(minutes=int(value))
        return self.talks

    def show_output(self):
        while not len(self.talk_list) is 0:
            print('Track %s' % Track.id)
            self.__prepare_output(9, 12)
            print('%s - %s' % (self.lunch, 'Lunch'))
            self.__prepare_output(13, 17)
            print('%s - %s' % (self.day_end, 'Networking Event'))
            Track.id += 1

    def __prepare_output(self, start, end):
        for time, title in sorted(self.get_talks(start, end).items()):
            print(time, '-', title)
        # clear previous entries
        self.talks.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Track()
    a.show_output()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are some general comments:

- Be more consistent about whitespace, particularly around operators. It will make your code easier to read.
- I have two suggestions for the way you store instance variables in your Timing objects:

  - Each line is nearly identical. I think it would be better to have a function

    ```
    def time_after_start(hours):
        return datetime.min + timedelta(hours=hours)
    ```

    and call that for each function. It will make the code a little cleaner, and it’ll be easier to see the difference between the lines.
  - I’d keep them as datetime objects, and only cast to strings when you actually need to print them. Use strings for pretty-printing, not for storing structured data. If you need to modify those variables later, you’d have to parse them back from strings first.

    (I know you aren’t changing them here; it’s just a general habit I dislike.)
- You open `test.txt`, but never close it again. And you’re creating a list with all the lines, which is inefficient for memory. It would be better to go through the lines one at a time, as follows:

  ```
  with open('test.txt') as f:
      for line in f:
          # do stuff with the line

  return __talks
  ```

  This is more memory efficient and idiomatic.
- I’m not sure why you feel the need to put two underscores on the `talks` variable; I think it just looks weird and would get rid of it.
- In `get_talks()`, you cast the result of `self.talk_list.items()` to a list, and I’m not sure why you’ve done that. It’s fine to iterate directly over `.items()` without turning it into a list first.

  Likewise, we know that the values are int’s, because we set them up as such in `extract_input()`. So casting to int() is just redundant.
- Rather than iterating over `key, value`, I’d choose variable names that reflect what those elements in the dictionary mean. How about

  ```
  for talk, minutes in self.talk_list.items():
  ```

  That will make it easier to follow the intent of your code.
- In `show_output()`, the if statement is a bit weird. I think you’re trying to say “if there are still elements in self.talk_list, carry on”, which is better expressed as

  ```
  if self.talk_list:
  ```

  I think that’s easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

First off, negative indexing **does** work in Python, so the below `except` block will never execute. Also, when you try to access a list element that doesn't exist, it'll raise an `IndexError`, not a `ValueError`.

```
try:
    minutes = int(minutes[:-3])
# negative indexing raises error, so it means it's lightning
except ValueError:
    minutes = 5
```

Why is the variable `__talks` in the method `extract_input` prefixed with two leading underscores? The variable is local to the function, so there's no need to make it "private".

Finally, add some [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to describe your functions/classes. Docstrings are special comments that you use to describe your functions. An example docstring looks something like this:

```
def my_func( ... ):
    """
    Describe what your function does
    in addition to it's arguments.
    """
    ...
```

Comment: Negative indexing works; the test is supposed to catch lightning talks which don't have a time duration like `45min`at the end of the line;  Negative indexing doesn't raise valueerror, doing `int("lightn")` does. (Testing for `line.endswith('lightning')` for lighining talks would be clearer, and keeping exceptions as error handling for misformatted talks with durations would be neater).